# How to access a file with only the filepath as a string in Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I currently have the filepath of the file that I want to access as a string, but I'm not sure if Qt has a feature that allows you to access that file with only the filepath.

I'm saving the filepath to an INI file and I want to take that filepath to open the json file that is a part of that path. This is what I've tried so far - the code would go into openFile()

```
void saveFileLocation(QString filename) 
{
    QSettings *settings = new QSettings(Ve::Widgets::SettingsWindowWidget::INI_FILE, QSettings::IniFormat);
    QDir dir;
    QString filePath = dir.filePath(filename);
    settings->setValue("projectFile", filePath);
    on_menuRecent_Files_aboutToShow(filePath);
}
void openFile(QString filepath) 
{   
    *insert code here*
}
void on_menuRecent_Files_aboutToShow(QString filePath)
{
    QAction* openAction = ui->menuRecent_Files->addAction(filePath);
    connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openFile(filePath)));


}
```

I want to implement an action option, that has text of the filepath, and when clicked, opens up the file that I want to access. Is there a Qt feature that allows you to do this?

Comment: "opens the file" as in "open the file to read its bytes" or "launch the associated application"?

Comment: `saveFileLocation()` is leaking the `settings` object.  You don't really need to use `new` at all in that code, but if you do use it, you need to `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: What you mean by access is very vague. With that said `Qt` supports both options that @MatteoItalia mentioned.

Comment: I mean "launch the associated application"

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl

Comment: Would the openUrl open json files? So far it's not working

Comment: Did you use the `file:` syntax? You may want: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile

Comment: "launch the associated application" requires that there is an associated application for json files. What happen when you double-click on one? Also when replying to comments, you need to tag people (like this: @MaiVo) otherwise they're no going to see your comment replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- To open with system default associated application:

```cpp
void openFile(QString filepath) 
{   
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile( filepath ));
}
```

- To open with specific application:

```cpp
void openFile(QString filepath) 
{   
    // open with notepad
    QProcess::execute("notepad \""+ filepath +"\"");
}
```

Hope it helps you.